# Is the speed at which someone does math inborn, or can it be increased through practice?

Tags: education

Is there scientific evidence (or at least personal experience) that shows that daily practice of math problems increases the speed at which those problems are solved?

Mind you I am not talking about being "better" at math as in being able to do harder problems. I am talking about being more efficient. As in being able to solve 555+666 in 20 seconds instead of 30 after doing a month of math addition problems each morning.

I wonder if there is such a thing as a "math muscle" that improves the speed at which one does math, because I am myself slow in math.

Comment: It can certainly be decreased through lack of practice. :)

Comment: I recall research that supermarket cashiers are -- or used to be, before the ubiquity of computers -- much better at arithmetic than mathematicians. But I can't find the research back now.

Comment: That's why we memorize multiplication tables

Comment: Seems like you're talking about standard rote-based arithmetic, not mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you practice *anything,* you get better at it, don't you?

I did a google search for “research arithmetic speed practice” and I found a Ed.D. thesis that studied a problem pretty close to what you're asking:

[The relationship between timed drill practice and the increase of automaticity of basic multiplication facts for regular education sixth graders](https://scholarworks.waldenu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1824&context=dissertations) by Nelly P. Knowles (Walden University Ed.D. thesis, 2010).  From the abstract:

> This 8-week quasi-experimental quantitative study, based in cognitive development and theories of the construction of memory, used a 3-level independent variable experimental design to determine if there was a relationship between teachers’ implementation of timed drill practices and the students’ level of automaticity with regard to basic multiplication facts in 9 sixth-grade, regular education math classes. The control group received no intervention, the first treatment group received weekly timed drill practice for 3 minutes, and a second treatment group received daily timed drill practice for 3 minutes. Analysis of variance (ANOVA) procedures were used to measure the differences in pretest and posttest scores among the 3 treatment groups. Although no significant difference was found among the 3 groups’ pretest performance, a significant difference among posttest performance was
>   found. Scheffe’ post hoc analysis revealed that the **students who were administered daily
>   timed practice drills performed statistically higher on the posttest than did the control
>   group and first treatment group**. Similarly, students in the weekly timed practice drill
>   group had statistically significant higher gain scores than did students in the no treatment group.

The abstract doesn't mention it, but the concept of *automaticity* seems to measure what you're interested in: speed of recalling facts to perform arithmetic algorithms.